# ASP.Net MVC validation message localization

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, localization, data-annotations

I have an application that I use for localization. I have added the necessary resource files for the different  languages and I get the localized string for labels based on the current culture. So that's fine. I have also added the `DataAnnotations` for `Required` like below :

```
    [Display(Name = "Date_Of_Birth", ResourceType = typeof(i18n.Resources.Generic))]
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = (typeof(i18n.Resources.Generic)), ErrorMessageResourceName = "InvalidDate")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime Date_Of_Birth { get; set; }
```

I have localized the error message and have the corresponding values stored against "InvalidDate". However, I do not get the correct full error message. I get the default "required" message which is a mix of English and the current culture.For example, I get, `The field XXXX is required` where XXXX is the name of the field in the localized format.
Why is the localized error message not being picked up from the correct localized files?

Thanks in advance for any help.